# [] in postman response php

Tags: php, android, postman

```
<?php 

    require_once 'DbConnect.php';

    //an array to display response
    $response = array();

    //if it is an api call 
    //that means a get parameter named api call is set in the URL 
    //and with this parameter we are concluding that it is an api call

    if(isset($_GET['apicall'])){

        switch($_GET['apicall']){

            case 'signup':
                //checking the parameters required are available or not 
                if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('username','email','password','gender'))){

                    //getting the values 
                    $username = $_POST['username']; 
                    $email = $_POST['email']; 
                    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
                    $gender = $_POST['gender']; 

                    //checking if the user is already exist with this username or email
                    //as the email and username should be unique for every user 
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?");
                    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $email);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->store_result();

                    //if the user already exist in the database 
                    if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
                        $response['error'] = true;
                        $response['message'] = 'User already registered';
                        $stmt->close();
                    }else{

                        //if user is new creating an insert query 
                        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, gender) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
                        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $username, $email, $password, $gender);

                        //if the user is successfully added to the database 
                        if($stmt->execute()){

                            //fetching the user back 
                            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, id, username, email, gender FROM users WHERE username = ?"); 
                            $stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
                            $stmt->execute();
                            $stmt->bind_result($userid, $id, $username, $email, $gender);
                            $stmt->fetch();

                            $user = array(
                                'id'=>$id, 
                                'username'=>$username, 
                                'email'=>$email,
                                'gender'=>$gender
                            );

                            $stmt->close();

                            //adding the user data in response 
                            $response['error'] = false; 
                            $response['message'] = 'User registered successfully'; 
                            $response['user'] = $user; 
                        }
                    }

                }else{
                    $response['error'] = true; 
                    $response['message'] = 'required parameters are not available'; 
                }

            break; 

            case 'login':
                //for login we need the username and password 
                if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('username', 'password'))){
                    //getting values 
                    $username = $_POST['username'];
                    $password = md5($_POST['password']); 

                    //creating the query 
                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, username, email, gender FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
                    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$username, $password);

                    $stmt->execute();

                    $stmt->store_result();

                    //if the user exist with given credentials 
                    if($stmt->num_rows > 0){

                        $stmt->bind_result($id, $username, $email, $gender);
                        $stmt->fetch();

                        $user = array(
                            'id'=>$id, 
                            'username'=>$username, 
                            'email'=>$email,
                            'gender'=>$gender
                        );

                        $response['error'] = false; 
                        $response['message'] = 'Login successfull'; 
                        $response['user'] = $user; 
                    }else{
                        //if the user not found 
                        $response['error'] = false; 
                        $response['message'] = 'Invalid username or password';
                    }
                }
            break; 

            default: 
                $response['error'] = true; 
                $response['message'] = 'Invalid Operation Called';
        }

    }else{
        //if it is not api call 
        //pushing appropriate values to response array 
        $response['error'] = true; 
        $response['message'] = 'Invalid API Call';
    }

    //displaying the response in json structure 
    echo json_encode($response);

    //function validating all the paramters are available
    //we will pass the required parameters to this function 
    function isTheseParametersAvailable($params){

        //traversing through all the parameters 
        foreach($params as $param){
            //if the paramter is not available
            if(!isset($_POST[$param])){
                //return false 
                return false; 
            }
        }
        //return true if every param is available 
        return true; 
    }
```

[image]

I keep getting [] in reponse of postman.What i am expecting is

https://i2.wp.com/www.simplifiedcoding.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/user-registration.png?w=954&ssl=1

Please help me.  I am trying to implement login functionality in my android app using php and as i am not aware of php, i am not sure what is wrong. Please help

Comment: make "id" in x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 0):

You have to just create The object for login details like : **user_email,user_id,user_gender,user_name,etc** you have not need to encode your json in to Array ,So just pass objects

**E.G** :

```
{
    status=true/false,
    message="your message",
    user_id="user@gmail.com",
    ,etc(Other objects)
}
```

You have to just get user data based on its ID and Just do above:

```
$myObj->name = "John";  //fetch user name
$myObj->age = 30;       //fetch user age
$myObj->city = "New York"; //fetch user city 

$myJSON = json_encode($myObj);   // edcode JSON
```

Comment: Can youshow me where i need to make changes and what exact changes i need to make as i have no knowledge of php.Please

Comment: i have not good knowledge for PHP but i think you have to remove creating array $user = array(
                                'id'=>$id, 
                                'username'=>$username, 
                                'email'=>$email,
                                'gender'=>$gender
                            );

Comment: I don't think thats the error because i just copied the code from simplified coding

Comment: I also checked the code through php validator and it says the code is correct

Comment: I think you should have to check your query first its : `$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, id, username, email, gender FROM users WHERE username = ?");`

Comment: May be its returning a blank data thats y u getting  a blank array